# using javascript to display content

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Quick question, why this is not working?

```
if ( xmlhttp.responseText )
{
    location.href = "result.php"
    document.getElementById( 'page-result' ).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;      
}
```

What I want to do is put search result on div on another page.

Comment: As Juhana said, this is not jQuery. This is standard JavaScript. If you want jQuery ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to your next page by passing the message in the query string like...

```
if ( xmlhttp.responseText )
{
    location.href = "result.php?responseText=" + encodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

In result.php, output the content of the parameter "responseText" wherever you want.

ex. in php: `<?php echo $_GET["responseText"]; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Each HTML page is independent; the browser starts from a clean slate on each page so you can't manipulate the next page's DOM from the previous page like this. You have to pass the information to the next page using GET or POST (or cookies or session or...) and handle the information separately there.